# How can I deploy a new service in Juju GUI specifying the destination machine?

Tags: juju

I would like to deploy a new service in the juju GUI specifying on which machine it should run. I mean the equivalent of doing `juju deploy --to 0 mysql`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GUI does not support this yet.  We expect to be starting work on this (containerization and machine support) very soon.